# Entityframework Core 3 linq expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I just upgrade to EF 3 and one of my queries that used to work, gives an exception now

```
   ProductionRecords = _context.ProductionRecords
          .Where(r => r.DataCriacao.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
            .Select(pr => new ProductionRecordViewModel
            {
                Id = pr.Id,
                Operador = pr.Operador,
                DataCriacao = pr.DataCriacao,
                Celula = pr.Celula.Name,
                Turno = pr.Turno.Name,
                TotalPecasSemDefeito = pr.ReferenceRecords.Sum(c => c.Quantity),
                TotalPecasComDefeito = pr.DefectRecords.Sum(c => c.Quantidade),
                TotalTempoParado = pr.StopRecords.Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Duration.TotalMinutes)),
            })
          .AsNoTracking()
          .ToList();
```

The exception happens when i'm trying to sum the collection with the timespan with the duration....

How am i supposed to handle this now?

here is the exception

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   '(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: StopRecord
>   ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression:
>   EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ).Duration.TotalMinutes'
>   could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
>   be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
>   a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the exception

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Any .net methods or classes cannot be translated to the query. your convert.toint() and Duration.totalminutes is probably your issue. If you still want these in there, add .tolist() before your select.

Comment: Is `TotalTempoParado = pr.StopRecords pr.StopRecords.Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Duration.TotalMinutes))` a typo?

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes, fixed that

Comment: You should post this question to EF Core GitHub to see what's their vision of handling something like this. Apparently switching to client evaluation as suggested is not directly possible, and adding eager/lazy loading would make it highly inefficient.

Comment: @ivanstoev client evaluation is possible, if you call asnotracking, then tolist, then filter those results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's been a breaking change in EF3 that will not automatically revert to client side evaluation unless at the very end of query chain (which your `Convert.ToInt32(c.Duration.TotalMinutes)` was likely relying on).

Try rewriting your query like so:

```
 ProductionRecords = _context.ProductionRecords
      .Where(r => r.DataCriacao.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(pr => new ProductionRecordViewModel
        {
            Id = pr.Id,
            Operador = pr.Operador,
            DataCriacao = pr.DataCriacao,
            Celula = pr.Celula.Name,
            Turno = pr.Turno.Name,
            TotalPecasSemDefeito = pr.ReferenceRecords.Sum(c => c.Quantity),
            TotalPecasComDefeito = pr.DefectRecords.Sum(c => c.Quantidade),
            TotalTempoParado = pr.StopRecords pr.StopRecords.Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Duration.TotalMinutes)),
        })
      .ToList();
```

**UPD** As it's been rightly pointed out in the comments - this will basically defer the `.Select` evaluation to the client side. Which will likely cause performance issues. Most likely this behaviour has been the reason this change was made to EF Core 3 in the first place.

I don't have enough specifics to recommend you a proper solution, but it seems you can't really get away from loading `StopRecords` on all your results. Which is where writing a custom method translator can help you. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191856/using-ef-core-2-2-to-decrypt-a-string-using-sql-server-decryptbykey/59192479#59192479) on how to do that. I quickly checked EF Core 3 source and it seems [IMethodCallTranslator](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/9abd61d3fb4cdd1041f25fe2e10c70ee3dc4055e/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/IMethodCallTranslator.cs) is still there. Which means you have pretty high chance of building a custom function that will convert dates to TotalMinutes in SQL.

Comment: also just be aware AsNoTracking has to be before AsEnumerable after

Comment: Worth noting that this will likely cause additional queries to be made to each of the three tables being summed in the Select clause. Potentially N+1 times

Comment: @devNull i know but this will do until i can optimize the timespan

Comment: @devNull Or either NRE or 0 sums in case lazy loading is not enabled. The "answer" basically repeats the exception message and the proposed client side evaluation solution there, which is not good in general.

Comment: Be careful from an open use of IEnumerable data process, as it processing at the app level while it is a resource costly.

Comment: @IvanStoev fair point, I added a bit more context and a proposed way to solve the root cause properly. Hopefully that adds enough value to the OP and community

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to teach EF Core how to sum a timespan, how about adding a computed column to the database?

```cs
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
        public int Minutes { get; }


        entity.Property(e => e.Minutes)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Duration)");
```

Comment: I like this approach, i get to keep my query and just use the computed column which is more performant. I don't make it the right question because i already have accepted.