# EF Core 3.x - simple LINQ with Include can not be translated, client evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have a simple LINQ expression:

```
public List<Project> GetCheckedProjects(List<PickedUp> displayCollection)
        {
            IQueryable<Project> query = _context.Projects
                .OrderBy(project => project.CompletionDate)
                .Where(project => displayCollection.Any(item => item.ProjectID == project.ProjectID))
                .Include(project => project.TechnologiesProjects)
                .ThenInclude(techproj => techproj.Technology);
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

that drops me an runtime exception:

> 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .OrderBy(p => p.CompletionDate)
> .Where(p => __displayCollection_0
> .Any(item => item.ProjectID == p.ProjectID))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.'

In [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) it is mentioned, that in **EF Core 3.x** were breaking changes, and they prevent client evaluation. And

> In such cases, you can explicitly opt into client evaluation by
> calling methods like AsEnumerable or ToList (AsAsyncEnumerable or
> ToListAsync for async). By using AsEnumerable you would be streaming
> the results, but using ToList would cause buffering by creating a
> list, which also takes additional memory.

In my case, when using `AsEnumerable()` I am geting an exception:

> IEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'Include' (...)

Also simple using `ToList()` at very end of expression, [like in this SO answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401587)r, does not bring any positive result.

In **EF Core 2.x** my LINQ works fine. How to walk around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting the ids into separate collection and using `Contains`:

```
    public List<Project> GetCheckedProjects(List<PickedUp> displayCollection)
    {
        var ids = displayCollection.Select(item => item.ProjectID).ToList();
        IQueryable<Project> query = _context.Projects
            .OrderBy(project => project.CompletionDate)
            .Where(project => ids.Contains(project.ProjectID))
            .Include(project => project.TechnologiesProjects)
            .ThenInclude(techproj => techproj.Technology);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Or, since this code will be translated to query you can do it in one line:

```
IQueryable<Project> query = _context.Projects
            .OrderBy(project => project.CompletionDate)
            .Where(project => displayCollection.Select(item => item.ProjectID).Contains(project.ProjectID))
            .Include(project => project.TechnologiesProjects)
            .ThenInclude(techproj => techproj.Technology);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ef Core might be having trouble with the line:

```
displayCollection.Any(item => item.ProjectID == project.ProjectID)
```

Try doing it this way

```
public List<Project> GetCheckedProjects(List<PickedUp> displayCollection)
    {
        IQueryable<Project> queryAll = _context.Projects
            .OrderBy(project => project.CompletionDate)                
            .Include(project => project.TechnologiesProjects)
            .ThenInclude(techproj => techproj.Technology);
        
        var query = queryAll
              .ToList()
              .Where(project => displayCollection.Any(item => item.ProjectID == project.ProjectID));       
    
        return query;
    }
```

I think this should work because the EF core will not be translating the Where clause into a sql query. And reqular LINQ should be able to do it on a List.

The downside (if it works) is that you are going to loop through the entire database table when you call ".ToList()"

Comment: Actually it gives me the same exception like before.