# Decrypting data using EF Core 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am trying to find out how to use EF Core to decrypt data that is column encrypted with a Symmetric Key. In SQL Server, I would use these commands to get my data:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY My_Key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE myCert;
SELECT  CONVERT(char, DecryptByKey(soc_sec_no))
FROM MyDatabase WHERE arid_identifier=0001882
```

How can I do this from EF Core 3? I see a lot of articles on how to do this from Entity Framework 6 (non-core) and I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191856/using-ef-core-2-2-to-decrypt-a-string-using-sql-server-decryptbykey), but the code did not work for me.

Comment: Have you noticed that the author of the response even updated his [github](https://github.com/tkhadimullin/ef-core-custom-functions/tree/feature/ef-3.1-version) for 3.1?

Comment: Yes I did. That was the code I Used, but it kept throwing exceptions

Comment: Still the author (Timur) seems to be present on SO (he has a last seen of 3h ago)... If you are able to make a test case you are probably better trying to contact him through his github (opening an issue) or commenting in his response.

Comment: @xanatos -  On his Github, there seems to be an outstanding issue open that is similar to the issue I am facing. He hasn't addressed it though, It's been open for a while.

Comment: I've taken a look... It is going well... I can decrypt with OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestKey DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD. I think with cert is the same. Unsure if writing is possible however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with https://github.com/tkhadimullin/ef-core-custom-functions/tree/feature/ef-3.1-version .

I've put the changes on https://github.com/xanatos/ef-core-custom-functions/tree/feature/ef-3.1-version . Note that there are three commits, one for EF Core 3.1, one for EF Core 3.1.11 (no changes necessary), one for EF Core 5.0.2 (some changes necessary).

Sadly there were various small bugs in the code that I had to correct. The part about `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` in fact wasn't tested and was commented out by the author.

Changes necessary:

**class Repo:**

A transaction is needed to keep together the various SQL commands. The indexes of the parameters are wrong. I've added some protection against injection attacks vs the symmetric key name and password (probably useless because these two things should be very protected)

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetAllById(int id)
{
    // Transaction to keep together the two ExecuteSqlRaw with the query
    DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

    DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DECLARE @Open NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ' + QUOTENAME(@p0, '[') + ' DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@p1, '''') + N';'; EXEC sp_executesql @Open", SymmetricKeyName, SymmetricKeyPassword);

    var filteredSet = Set.Include(x => x.Table2)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .Where(x => x.Table2.IsSomething)
        .Select(m => new Model
        {
            Id = m.Id,
            //Decrypted = EF.Functions.Decrypt(SymmetricKeyPassword, m.Encrypted).ToString(),
            Decrypted = EF.Functions.DecryptByKey(m.Encrypted2).ToString(), // since the key's opened for session scope - just relying on it should do the trick
            Table2 = m.Table2,
            Encrypted = m.Encrypted,
        }).ToList();

    DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DECLARE @Close NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY ' + QUOTENAME(@p0, '[') + ';'; EXEC sp_executesql @Close", SymmetricKeyName);

    DbContext.Database.CommitTransaction();

    return filteredSet;
}
```

**class TranslateImpl:**

Fixed some problems with the handling of arguments (2 arguments aren't always present, and if there is only one the method crashes)

```
public SqlExpression Translate(SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList<SqlExpression> arguments)
{
    if (method == _encryptMethod)
    {
        var args = new[] { arguments[1], arguments[2] }; // cut the first parameter from extension function
        return _expressionFactory.Function(instance, "ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE", args, typeof(byte[]));
    }

    if (method == _decryptMethod)
    {
        var args = new[] { arguments[1], arguments[2] }; // cut the first parameter from extension function
        return _expressionFactory.Function(instance, "DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE", args, typeof(byte[]));
    }

    if (method == _decryptByKeyMethod)
    {
        var args = new[] { arguments[1], }; // cut the first parameter from extension function
        return _expressionFactory.Function(instance, "DECRYPTBYKEY", args, typeof(byte[]));
    }

    return null;
}
```

**script dbSchema.sql**

The script can now encrypt text in two different ways (passphrase or symmetric key)

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY [TestKeyWithPassword] WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestPassword'
GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [TestKeyWithPassword] DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestPassword'
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Models] ([Id], [Encrypted], [Table2Id]) 
VALUES (
    1, 
    --ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('TestPassword', 'Encrypted with Passphrapse'), 
    ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_GUID('TestKeyWithPassword'), 'Encrypted with Symmetric Key With Password'), 
    1)
```

**Big note about .ToString()**

There is a `.ToString()` after the `Decrypt`/`DecryptByKey`. It is translated to a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ...)` by EF Core. If you want something different you'll have to create some `DBFunctions` to do it (it is quite simple, take the example from `DbFunctionsExtensions.Encrypt`, done in my git)

**Big note about encrypting on save**

In all of this, I'm not sure how you would implement the encryption part. While you have some control on the `SELECT` generated by EF Core, you have much smaller control on the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.